# Returning search results based off checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I use the following code to filter data from `SQL` and it works fine. However, below code is vulnerable to SQL injection, but all the `$post` values are checkbox value (it's not user input).  So can I use below code?

Or do I need to use "prepared statement" as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767651/4826112)? I can only send number in array.

**Conn.php**

```
    try {

    //create PDO connection 
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DBHOST . ";port=3306;dbname=" . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
    exit;
}
```

**INDEX**

```
<div class="md-radio my-1">
     <input type="radio" class="filter_all cate" name="cate" id="car" value="Car">
     <label for="car">Car</label>
</div>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            filter_data();
            function filter_data() {
                $('.filter_data');
                var action = 'fetch_data';
                var cate = get_filter('cate');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "fetch.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        action: action,
                        cate: cate
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.filter_data').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            function get_filter(class_name) {
                var filter = [];
                $('.' + class_name + ':checked').each(function () {
                    filter.push($(this).val());
                });
                return filter;
            }
            $('.filter_all').click(function () {
                filter_data();
            });
        });
```

**fetch.php**

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {

 $query = "SELECT * FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1'";

if (isset($_POST["cate"])) {
    $cate = implode("','", $_POST["cate"]);
    $query .= "AND sca IN('" . $cate . "')";
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$total_row = $stmt->rowCount();
$output = '';
if ($total_row > 0) {
    foreach ($result as $row) {
    $output .= '<a href="/single_view.php?p=' . $row['link'] . '>' . $row['link']. '</a>
 }
} else {
    $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
}
echo $output;
}
```

Comment: This question is off topic and " all the $post values are checkbox value(its not user input)" is a grave delusion.

Comment: @YourCommonSense any solution? as per your answer how do i use word in `array`

Comment: Just exactly as shown in the answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense i tried but it does nothing no error it triggers `else {
    $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
}`

Comment: Here is my instruction on [how to debug your database interactions](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve). Please follow it to find out why doesn't your query find the data

Comment: @YourCommonSense i tried https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in and couldn't get can make a short example with it, what should i replace in above code.

Comment: This question is off-topic because of the use of variables that are not defined within the code, examples are `$conn` and `$query`.

Comment: @pacmaninbw have look at code added `$conn` and `$query`

Comment: How can this possibly be working as intended? `$parameter` and `$hashed` aren't ever declared.  We don't fix broken code here.

Comment: @mickmackusa `$parameter` and `$hashed` are just link for page. and i have updated my question have a look at it.

Comment: @mickmackusa this is what i did there i get `id` and follewed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12102882/3836908

Comment: Please do not update questions after they have been answered, especially please do not update code after the question has been answered. Please see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: @pacmaninbw it says `Do not change the code in the question` i have just added a`if` statement in question.

Answer (score 1):

Applying YCS's tutorial can't be dumbed down any further, so I suppose I'll write it out.

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $query = "SELECT link FROM allpostdata WHERE sts = '1'";

    if (!empty($_POST["cate"])) {
        $query .= " AND sca IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST["cate"]) - 1) . "?)";
    } else {
        $_POST["cate"] = []; // in case it is not set 
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($_POST["cate"]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if (!$result) {
        exit('<h3>No Data Found</h3>');
    }
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo "<a href=\"/single_view.php?p={$row['link']}\">{$row['link']}</a>";
    }
}
```

I assume this will display your links side by side.  You may want to style them a bit to position the links in a user friendly fashion.

Additionally, `$('.filter_data');` is doing nothing and can be removed.

I'd probably change the `filter_data()` declaration to something more brief:

```
function filter_data() {
    $.post(
       "fetch.php",
       {action: 'fetch_data', cate: get_filter('cate')}
    )
    .done(function(data) {
        $('.filter_data').html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: a small change in question what if i have multiple `if` statement in `query`, and what about `SQL injection` there is no need of using `prepared statement`